# How would to compare two timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, time, timestamp

In my application, I have two **UTC timestamp**, need to compare them. How would I get just the greater timestamp?

```js
var ts1=1611169043381; //UTC timestamp in string format
var ts2=1611184342102; //UTC timestamp in string format
```

After compare want to know which timestamp is greater than the other

In JSON st1 is in string format

```
"st1": {
    "value": "1611169043381",           
    "source": "CRM_UI",
    "sourceId": "info@pearagon.com",
    "updatedByUserId": 8966293,
    
}
```

Comment: `Math.max(ts1,ts2)`

Comment: `ts1 > ts2` - if true `ts1` is greater

Comment: also, please read it https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Answer (score 0):

As these timestamps represent the milliseconds since epoch, you could just use `ts1 > ts2` to find out wether `ts1` is greater. If your values are inside of an object like `st1`, just do `st1.value > st2.value`.